# DotNet Core C# Concurrency Entity Framework (Duplicate Key Value unique Constraints)

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

TL&DR: Several concurrent Tasks trying to place identical records into a database; Essentially SEVERAL tasks are being spun up and opening up several files that could be identical.

It is vital to save all the information, in a heavily nested table, based on the IP Address;  Here is what I have tried so far in the last 4 days of work (even during Christmas!)

- Tried to use a Transaction, within a do while() loop (with context.Rollback(). [Didn't work!]
- Tried to Put Random Sleeps within each of the Inserts to Stop Race Condition [Didn't work!]
- Made Code no longer Asyc . [Didn't work!]
- Current algorithm doesn't work and peg's CPU! [Doesn't work!]\
- Seperately add EACH object to the Table individually [Didn't work!]

Each of the Objects increments, during insert.  This is why this doesn't make sense. I am at at a loss of words.

Object Relationships

```
IP has many Incidents;
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `Vendor vendorInstancer = vendorInstance;`? Is it supposed to copy the instance? Could you also include the code of your entities to see how they are setup? Where do values for `Vendor vendorInstance` and  `AC acInstance` come from? For which table do you get the error?

Comment: Its just a new instantiantion of Vendor;  new Vendor(). I made it easier for you, by changing the code.

Comment: have you tried calling  context.SaveChanges(); once at the end?

Comment: Can't remember for sure, but don't you need to reload the entity after save to get the values saved to the database? That is, is the line `IncidentId = newIncidentToAdd.IncidentID` really getting you the correct IncidentID rather than default int value?

Comment: Yes I tried saving it once.   Npgsql.PostgresException: 23503: insert or update on table "Vendors" violates foreign key constraint "FK_Vendors_Incidents_IncidentID"

Comment: @imantas : I stepped through the code, it doesn't seem like you need to reload it. The value is correct. As you see the error is on the dependent variables.

Comment: ... what happened to the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have a problem in these lines:

```
Vendor vendorInstancer = new Vendor();
vendorInstance.IncidentID = IncidentId;
context.Vendors.Add(vendorInstancer);
```

Note the variable names. You create `vendorInstancer` but update ID of the `vendorInstance`. That is, not the entity you're saving to the database. Hard to spot that one letter difference.